# keep second element while mouse leave (hover) first element

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I try to create a div-element by hover over an element using the plugin hoverIntent.

```
<div class="element" style="with: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000, margin: 5px">Main element</div>
```

Will get:

```
<div class="element" style="with: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000, margin: 5px">Main element</div>
<div class="element new" style="with: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000, margin: 5px">New element</div>
```

**hoverIntent:**

```
$(document).hoverIntent({
        over: function() {
            $(this).after('<div class="element new" style="with: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000, margin: 5px">New element</div>');
        },
        out: function(){
            $('.new').slideUp(200, function() { $(this).remove(); });
        },
        selector: '.element'
});
```

I don't know how to fix the problem, that the new element always disapears as the user moves the mouse from the first element to the second.
The new element should still be shown if the user moves the mouse over the main element or the new element. Only if the mouse moves somewhere else, the new element should disappear.

Comment: Try to append the content, so you stay in the same box(div block), but not putting element outside that div, and afterwards while pointing to newly created div the ```out``` event is being called..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite your class-selector, the hoverIntent will trigger for that one element you hover over at the initial state, therefore the `out`-function will trigger for this element. The new element is not included here.

You will see that of you look at the output of `console.log($(this))`. Only one object is included ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t1uy21zm/))
So only for that element in `$(this)` the `out`-function will work.

I would recommend to wrap your elements into another div:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element" style="with: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000, margin: 5px">Main element</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).hoverIntent({
    over: function () {
        $(this).append('<div class="element new" style="with: 100%; height: 50px; border: 1px solid #000, margin: 5px">New element</div>');
    },
    out: function () {
        $('.new').slideUp(200, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    },
    selector: '.wrapper'
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cnf6uudm/)

To wrap you elements dynamically into a `div` you can use this snippet:

```
var wrapper = $('<div />').addClass('wrapper');
$('.element').wrap(wrapper);
```

[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/efd7zxzc/1/)

Comment: My problem with that is, that it has to be dynamic. The new element is just a temporary element. If the user decides to keep it (press a button in the new div), the class ".new" will be removed and the element is permanent (as all other elements). So, if I has to wrap it, it has to be wrapped in a dynamic way

Comment: @user3142695 is you main-element dynamic too ? If not, then the wrapper can be static, as you append all the other dynamic divs inside.

Comment: Unfortunatly it cannot be static :-( I tried to use wrap() to create the wrapper, but then I have to do a second hover event. I don't get it...

Comment: @user3142695 I updated my answer, I don't know if I get it right now, if not, can you please provide an exampler with what you've tried ?